# Why list of related items is not showing in API?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Field list_items is not showing in the API request.
I want to create request to get TodoItem with list of ListItem objects related to TodoItem.

I tried to change types of list_items value to another, but it isn't working.

Response right now:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "L",
        "title": "Some title",
        "due_date": null,
        "created_at": "2022-08-02T09:26:07.149081Z",
        "text_value": "",
        "url_value": ""
    }
]
```

Response I need:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "L",
        "title": "Some title",
        "due_date": null,
        "created_at": "2022-08-02T09:26:07.149081Z",
        "text_value": "",
        "url_value": ""
        "list_items":[
            Item #1,
            Item #2,
        ]
    }
]
```

models.py

```
class TodoItem(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(
        ('T', 'String'), ('L', 'List'), ('U', 'URL')))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    text_value = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=500)
    url_value = models.URLField(blank=True)  # TODO: add validator/test it


class ListItem(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    checked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    todo_item = models.ForeignKey(TodoItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = PositionField(default=0, unique_for_fields=('todo_item',))
```

serializers.py

```
class ListItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    todo_item = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=TodoItem.objects.all(), required=False, allow_null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        model = ListItem
        fields = ['id', 'value', 'position', 'todo_item']


class TodoItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_at = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()
    def get_list_items(self, obj):
        return ListItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = TodoItem
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the `related_name` in the `ForeignKey` field.

```
class ListItem(models.Model):
    ...
    todo_item = models.ForeignKey(TodoItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "list_items")
    position = PositionField(default=0, unique_for_fields=('todo_item',))
```

Then in the serializer, you can set the `list_items` field.

```
class TodoItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_at = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()
    list_items = ListItemSerializer(many= True, read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = TodoItem
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'title', 'due_at', 'created_at', 'text_value', 'url_value', 'list_items', )
```